# Find $a_j$ give m points as $(x_i,y_i)$ where: $i = 1,2,...,m$, $y=\sum_{j=0}^n a_j x^j \quad n < m$

Tags: statistics, least-squares

I have been trying to solve this problem, is this answer right?
it's my first time solving a problem in the curve fitting least-squares that has a finite series in it.

find $a_j$ give m points as $(x_i,y_i)$ where: $i = 1,2,...,m$, $y=\sum_{j=0}^n a_j x^j  \quad n < m$.
(the problem and answer in the picture)

[my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7lHL.png):

[image]

if wrong, what approach should I take to solve it?

Comment: Please include your work in the body of your question rather than as a link so that this question is self-contained.

Comment: sorry, it was my first time asking a question here.